# Outputting multiple values from a function in C++

Tags: c++, function, struct

I am pretty new to programming and I'm trying to build a code that does the following things:

1) Two short functions that return an equation.
2) Use those two equations in another function that will compute some things and return TWO variables. 
3) The main will then be in a different file that will use the two values outputted by the function described in step 2.

Currently, I have steps 1 and 2 in one file and function 2 is the main. I recall from trying to do something like this before that you can't call multiple functions this way. I think I have to make a header file that has all of the functions necessary? I'm not sure though. Also, I believe I need to create a struct to output the values to from function 2.

I have included portions of the codes below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std; 

//Solution to the linear dispersion relationship for a horizontal bottom. 
//Shallow Water Solution only

double f (double, double, double, double);
double df (double, double, double);

//Below is the struct I will then fill with the values calculated from 
//linear dispersion function
struct wave_info {
  double kn, L;
}

double linear_dispersion (double f, double df) {    
  // Deleted code...
  return kn;    
}

//Linear dispersion relation
double f(double kn, double omega, double g, double h) {
    return f;
}

//Differential of Linear dispersion relation. Necessary for N-R method
double df(double kn, double g, double h) {
    return df;
}
```

And the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std; 

int main () {
/*
 * Use values for wavelength (L) and wave number (k) calculated from linear 
 * dispersion program
 * 
 */

  // Deleted code ...

  return 0;

}
```

I have deleted the body of the code as I'm confused in how to call functions in this way. My main just needs to use two values calculated in the linear_dispersion function. I'm confused in how to call the linear_dispersion function correctly using the functions f and df.

Separately, the code works but I have not been able to bring the values calculated in linear_dispersion into my main.

Thanks in advance for any help! Let me know if you need more information or something is unclear.

Comment: you can always use pass by reference for outputting multiple values from a function.

Comment: I think I did answer the "two return values" part, but the _I'm confused in how to call the linear_dispersion function correctly using the functions f and df._ is a little confusing, could you clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your needs correctly, you can either use a custom struct or the built-in [`pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair)

e.g:

```
struct wave{
    int k;
    int L;
};

wave foo(){
    //some more intelligent calculations here :)
    return {5,6};
}

std::pair<int,int> foo2(){
    //some more intelligent calculations here :)
    return std::make_pair(4,5);
}

int main() {
    wave w = foo();
    std::pair<int,int> a = foo2();
    cout << w.k << " " << w.L << endl;
    cout << a.first << " " << a.second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

([demo](http://ideone.com/d1fn2E))

Comment: Ok I think that you did understand what I was asking... Just a few more questions (sorry for taking a while to write back) ... These may be silly questions but I'm still a noob here
1) when you say return {5,6} I'm assuming that 5 and 6 are corresponding to k and L? Or are they something else? 
2) I don't know the std::pair command, will look it up now. The way I think I undersatnd it though from your explanation is that it groups that return values together to be used as a pair in the main? In that case, what is the difference between the function foo() and std::pair? 

Thanks for the help

Comment: It's OK, I really think that you should look at the demo a bit... :) 1) Yes you're correct as you can see in the demo after calling `wave w = foo()`  printing `w.k` and `w.L` yields `5 6` respectively.
2) `std::pair` is not a command it's a built-in class.
Please clarify this: _what is the difference between the function foo() and std::pair_. As I said `std::pair` is a class and `std::make_pair` is a function that conveniently creates an instance of this class. `foo` returns a `wave` struct and `foo2` returns a `pair` of two `int`s you can see how to access the values in `pair` in the sample.

Comment: Ok i think I understand... so using std::pair and pairing my values that I want to return so that when I return using make_pair, it's similar to outputting a struct of the two variables, just different method! Hope this is right! I think I understand how to do this now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pass by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) to get multiple values from a function.
Sample code below:

```
void linear_dispersion (double &f, double &df) //return type void
{
double a , b, c , d;
f = f(a,b,c,d); 
df = df(a,b,c,d);

}

main()
{
double val1 , val2;
linear_dispersion (val1, val2);

cout<<val1<<","<<val2; //changed val1 & val2
}
```